# ref, table, label,xelatex

Tags: tables, xetex, cross-referencing

I have encountered a simple problem. 
I use "xelatex" and code my tables as below.
I want to cite this table, but it turns "??". How can I solve it?
Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\usepackage{indentfirst,amsmath,multicol,amssymb,booktabs,threeparttable,caption}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption {Moments}\label{Comparison}
\centering

\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllll} 
\toprule
& Data & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Model}  \\
\midrule \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example code doesn't have a `\ref{Comparison}`, but it sounds like you just need to run xelatex again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forget to code a line as \ref{Comparison}.

But it still returns "??".

That means I cannot call my table?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I cut your example code down to a minimal one maintaining the table and the `\resizebox` (for which `graphicx` is needed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption {Moments}\label{Comparison}
\centering

\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllll}
\toprule
& Data & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Model}  \\
\midrule \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

See Table~\ref{Comparison}.

\end{document}
```

The first time I compile this by running `xelatex`, I get the following.

[image]

The output of XeLaTeX informs you of what to do.

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

After running `xelatex` a second time, the reference is correctly resolved.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it still can not resolve my problem.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\usepackage{indentfirst,amsmath,multicol,amssymb,booktabs,threeparttable,caption}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{2pt}

\geometry{top=1.4in,bottom=1.in,left=1in,right=1in}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{grffile}
%\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig} 
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{floatrow}

Comment: @ChYh - Did you run XeLaTeX twice?

Comment: @ChYh if my answer doesn't solve your problem, then you need to edit your example such that it demonstrates the problem. What you posted doesn't compile as is and also contains a lot of unnecessary stuff. Try to produce a piece of code that compiles, does not contain extra packages, and still exhibits the problem. Otherwise, there's nothing we can do.